# HTML format on Django text field model

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to create a blog. I want to create blog content in admin panel and render the blog content with HTML format.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

In admin panel :
[Create blog content with HTML format in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgPOZ.jpg)

In template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ blog.content }}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Is there any template tags, model field, or anything to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply using the built in `safe` template tag.

In your template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ blog.content | safe }}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

check the docs for the same [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).

Comment: Avoid using the "safe" filter unless absolutely necessary. The "safe" filter disables automatic HTML escaping, which can lead to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks if untrusted data is used in a template.

Answer (score 1):

**You have some options.**

1. You can use a Content Management System (CMS) like [django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) or [Wagtail](https://wagtail.org/).
2. If you don't want to add the complexity of having a full CMS, you can add a simple rich text editor (WYSIWYG editor) like [CKEditor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [tiny](https://www.tiny.cloud/solutions/wysiwyg-django-rich-text-editor/).
3. Avoid using the "safe" filter unless absolutely necessary. The "safe" filter disables automatic HTML escaping, which can lead to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks if untrusted data is used in a template.